# How do I send video with Node to a client JavaScript blob and then display it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming

I want to send a video file to the client and display the video with .createObjectURL().

Node server.js:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  if (req.url == "/") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });

    res.end('<video id="video" src="" autoplay controls loop width="200px" height="200px" muted></video>' +
      '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>' +
      '<script src="blobvideo.js"></script>'); 
  }

  else if (req.url == "/blobvideo.js") {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/javascript" });
    fs.readFile('./blobvideo.js', function(err, data) {
      res.end(data.toString());
    });

  }

  else if (req.url == "/video") {
    fs.readFile('video.mp4', function(err, data) {
      res.end(data);
    });
  }
}).listen(3000);
```

Client blobvideo.js:

```
$.ajax( "/video" ).done(function(data) {
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(data.length);
  var view = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = data[i];
  }

  blob = new Blob([ab], { type: "video/mp4" });
  document.getElementById("video").src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

In this code, the video is sent all in one piece, and the video doesn't play. My questions:

1. How can I fix this to play the video?
2. How can I change it to stream the file rather than wait for the entire video to download?

**Edit for Clarification**

I want to use `Blob` and `.createObjectURL()` on the client because I am trying to build a peer-to-peer video implementation of the WebRTC RTCPeerConnection, so that static video data can be sent from the client to another client without sending it through the server.

Comment: This solution could help you : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images

Answer (score 0):

This is pure nodejs javascript which streams video/audio without outside library dependencies and requires NO client code ... launch it using :

```
node this_code.js
```

then point your client browser at

```
http://localhost:8888
```

Huge benefit is the browser client video rendering UI widgets just work - (ability to jump to some random media location, etc.)

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

// put any audio or video file here
var path = "/path/to/audio/or/video/file/local/to/server/cool.mp4";

var port = 8888;
var host = "localhost";

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  var stat = fs.statSync(path);
  var total = stat.size;

  if (req.headers.range) {

    // meaning client (browser) has moved the forward/back slider
    // which has sent this request back to this server logic ... cool

    var range = req.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

    var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
    res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(res);

  } else {

    console.log('ALL: ' + total);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(port, host);

console.log("Server running at http://" + host + ":" + port + "/");
```

enjoy,

Comment: See my edit. I would like to store the video data on the client in parts that I can send again to another client through WebRTC RTCPeerConnection. My end goal is beyond the scope of a single question, which is why I tried to break it down into playing a video after saving the data in JavaScript.

Comment: Off topic. @user3038754 goal is to rebuild buffer as image in the client side, not to stream a file from server.

Answer (score -2):

I would just serve video.mp4 as a static asset and set the `src` of the video element to the URL for that video.