# Downloading a Video from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the right approach to get a video from the Node.js server? I want to send a request to the node server, and be able to the file? Should I create an FTP server to handle this issue? or is there a way around using HTTP? Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429708/how-do-i-send-video-with-node-to-a-client-javascript-blob-and-then-display-it)

[Or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321027/how-to-send-files-with-node-js)

Just use your web server features. This is for sending video from the server. To retrieve it, use [axios](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/download-files-images-with-axios-in-node-js). Google will help you further.